# AppointmentType field is not available in Serviceappointment object

Tags: fsl, lightning-scheduler

We are working on FSL cloud and in that under service appointment object we were not able to see the AppointmentType standard field.
The strange thing is its available in one sand box but not coming in other sand box.
When checked the documentation its saying by default it will be available in healthcloud org but we are having both Healthcloud and FSL both.

[image]